# Does MacBook Air 11" (Early 2015) Broadwell support DisplayPort MST?

Tags: multiple-monitors, displayport, macbook-air, mst

Does MacBook Air (11-inch, Early 2015), powered by Broadwell with Intel HD Graphics 6000, and Thunderbolt 2 port (up to 20 Gbps), support DisplayPort 1.2 Multi-Stream Transport?

https://support.apple.com/kb/SP713 mentions nothing about MST.

Comment: Yes; Intel HD Graphics 4200 and above support DP 1.2 and MST.  What I cannot tell you is if OS X supports it.  I just know the hardware supports it because I use a similar setup with my SP3.

Comment: @Ramhound, hm, so, what about the software?  because my MacBook Air (mid-2013) doesn't seem to do MST.

Comment: So is the Macbook Air a 2013 model or a 2015 model?  Broadwell products were not even released until recently...I can confirm OS X has the capability based on some other results I found.  Products that were Haswell and older gained the DP 1.2 feature, products released before Haswell, were HD400 and below only supported DP 1.1 where applicable.

Comment: @Ramhound, which other results?  mid-2013 was Haswell already.

Comment: Clarify your question, your comment, conflicts with your question.  As for other resources, google, and search results I don't keep my history so I can't provide my results

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR: NO. Because... The OS does not support MST on your Air.** The hardware supports it (see: http://www.notebookcheck.net/Intel-HD-Graphics-6000.125588.0.html):

*"All Broadwell GPUs support OpenCL 2.0 and DirectX 12 (FL 11_1). The video engine can now decode H.265 using both fixed function hardware as well as available GPU shaders. **Up to three displays can be connected via DP 1.2/eDP 1.3 (max. 3840 x 2160 @ 60 Hz)** or HDMI 1.4a (max. 3840 x 2160 @ 24 Hz). HDMI 2.0, however, is not supported."*

I have a MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2015).

I have a matched pair of Dell U2414H monitors that support DP 1.2 (work beautiful on my Win10 gaming machine).

I can get the monitors to "work" on my MBAir using 1.2 (and/or) 1.1 mode on the monitors, **but NOT the intended results**:

- With mirroring ON, I get the same (desktop #1) on the MBAir as I do my two monitors **(three screens showing the same thing)**.
- With mirroring OFF,  I get (desktop #1) on the MBAir and (desktop #2) on **both** of my Dells **(one screen showing one thing, two screens showing a duplicated something else)**.
- What I would expect is MBAir = Desktop #1, Dell#1 = Desktop #2, Dell#2 Desktop #3

When I go into display preferences I can see that the Mac only sees one monitor attached (not two for a total of three to configure). After a TON of searching and reading the answer was right in front of me:

**"Supported displays and configurations"**

**... Multi-Stream Transport (MST) Displays**

These Mac computers support multi-stream transport (MST) displays at 60 Hz:

- MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013) and later
- MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015) and later
- Mac Pro (Late 2013)
- iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, Late 2014) and later

https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT206587

Notice anything missing?